ADO YAML conditional expressions not working
I'm trying to implement conditional expressions as per this article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-192-update#new-yaml-conditional-expressions
variables:  
    ${{ if or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release')) }}: 
      branchName: 'master'
    ${{ else }}: 
      branchName: 'develop'

However, I'm getting the error Unexpected value 'branchName'
I also tried a different way which is also erroring out.
 - name:  branchName
   ${{ if or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release')) }}: 
     value: 'master'
   ${{ else }}: 
     value: 'develop'


Test the same variables definition and it can work as expected. It seems that the format of the variables part should be correct. You can refer to the yaml sample in my answer and check if it has the same issue. If yes, you can share the full YAML sample with us.

On the other hand, can you confirm if you are using Azure DevOps Service or Azure DevOps Server On-Prem?

When we use the conditional expressions in YAML Pipeline, we need to pay attention to the indentation of expressions and variable definitions.
I have tested the YAML sample you shared. It can work as expected.
Here is my sample:
variables:  
 ${{ if or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release')) }}: 
  branchName: 'master'
 ${{ else }}: 
  branchName: 'develop'

steps:
- script: echo "$(branchName)"

Or
variables:  
- name:  branchName
  ${{ if or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release')) }}: 
   value: 'master'
  ${{ else }}: 
   value: 'develop'


steps:
- script: echo "$(branchName)"

Pipeline Validation:

On the other hand, ${{ else }} and ${{ elseif }} expressions in YAML Pipeline are available starting with Azure DevOps 2022 and aren't available for Azure DevOps Server 2020 and earlier versions of Azure DevOps Server.
If you are using Azure DevOps Server On-Prem, you need to check if the  server version supports using elseif and else clause.
Refer to this doc: Conditional insertion

@user18610347
I tested a similar setup to that of your first attempt, and here’s a version that works for me:

variables:
  ${{ if or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release')) }}:
    branchName: 'master'
  ${{ else }}:
    branchName: 'develop'

stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job: BuildJob
        steps:
          - script: echo "branchName is $(branchName)"


Here is the pipeline for your review
Please pay attention to indentation as this could be an issue if not properly done.

Conditional insertion has another example for your reference,


